# Xcode - Lost .h and .cpp file data after Moving src files

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, data-loss, file-recovery

I was planning on temporarily moving some of my .h and .cpp files out of my Xcode Projects src folder to the desktop. Upon doing so the entire class's code that I wrote was replaced with this

```
book����mark����8���8���ú��������ˇ��Iù`∂ﬂÀ¿A����ˇ��t��������

�������Users��������admin��������Desktop������Western������Fall 18������310������OpenFrameworks�������apps�����myApps�� �����GameFinal��������src������Item.h��0�������� ���0���@���P���`���l���Ñ���ê���†���¥���¿��������Ÿì����������€ì����������ﬁì����������≤ñ����������O~q����������1]s����������¶7ä����������9Dä����������:Dä����������í”ó����������ì”ó����������},ò�����0���������(��8��H��X��h��x��à��ò��®��∏��������A¿À>_Ä���������������������������������������������   ��������
������������ı�����  ��file:///�����Macintosh HD�������`t���������Aø"éÌ���$�����05F48E21-DF9C-344C-AD93-FC37BA933E0A�����Å������Ô�����Ô����������/��������NSURLDocumentIdentifierKey�������F���1�����dnib������������������������������h????����������� ��˛ˇˇˇ������������–���������»��������������@���������T��8������U��D������V��0������ ��¸������ ��l������ ��|������ ��∞������ ��ê������ ��†������  ��‹������0 ��0������¿��P������¿�� �������¿��`������–��0������–�����������¿�������"��8�������Ä,������
```

I have tried opening the file in textEdit to see if there was a previous history to revert to and there was not. I tried <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the src folder and this did nothing, I tried bringing it back into Xcode and it looks the same. I had so much written and other unaffected classes depend on this file.

Comment: Looks like you have a problem. Someone who knows Macs better than I may suggest some file recover wizardry, but in the future may I recommend keeping back-ups or using a [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control)?

Comment: One issue I was having was working with someone who is on PC running Visual Studio, and when making my xcode project folder a git repo the PC user would see bad text encodings even after I set the encoding to UTF-8. Originally moving the files out of the project to a separate folder then sending that to repo was doing the trick. Until this happened. But your right, I am going to have to  make sure I back up my project folder before doing anything else.